# Make a table and render the data inside a table using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a dynamic table so that every time I press the "add" button, a new row will be created.

In my example below, it creates only 1 row with all the data under its header, but with all the 3 values in this case instead of create a new row.

I'm fetching the document from Firestore and the collection includes only 1 document with an array inside, in this case with 3 values.

**here is the screenshot of the table it creates:**

[image: Table]

**Expecteed table example:**

[image: Expected table]

Code:

```
export default class NutritionTableOfTheUser extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            tableData: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const dbRef = collection(db, 'data');
        onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
            let foods = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                foods.push(doc.data())
            });
            this.setState({ tableData: foods })
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container mt-3'>
                {/* table */}
                <table className='table table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Food</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.tableData.map((row, index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                    <td>{row.value}</td>
                                    <td>{row.quantity}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the code in the question looks problematic. It may be that the issue is with the database - that there's a single call to `doc.data()` which for some reason contains all the info together instead of being separated into multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the data you are getting from firebase collection, because you might have only one document in collection which results in rendering only one row in table.

Comment: There is 1 document that includes an array of 3 elements. So I need it to show the data from the array in the table in each row. (I forgot to mention that in the question).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only have a single document, and your `.value` and `.quantity` properties of the row are arrays (rather than numbers) - so doing `<td>{row.value}</td>` mashes all values of the array together.

Turn the `.data()` into the desired data format first, then set the state with it.

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const [obj] = doc.data();
    const tableData = obj.value.map((value, i) => ({
      value,
      quantity: obj.quantity[i]
    }));
    this.setState({ tableData })
});
```